# Error when cropping an image and using getDownloadURL()

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to utilise an image cropper (from ArthurHub GitHub) getting an error when typing getDownloadURL() i have put getStorage() in front using the getStorage() gets rid of the red line under getDownloadUrl however when I press crop I get the error message I have coded down the very end of this piece of code 'image cannot be cropped'. Does anyone know how to fix this

```
/*...*/ {
    ProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!= null)
    {
        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);
    }

    if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(requestCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we are updating your profile image");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile image stored successfully to firebase storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                        UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                                    {
                                        Intent selfIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(selfIntent);

                                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored to firebase database successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error occurred:" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occurred: Image can't be cropped try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please edit your question to give it a clear title (that isn't just the first line of the question), and then format the question so that it can be read clearly. There's some good guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Looks like we both are following the same tutorial. I got stuck here but you can solve it by following the code from this link. https://github.com/akshayejh/Lapit---Android-Firebase-Chat-App/issues/13